# How do I resume the music when I open the app again using MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have a button called music and when I click on it the MPMediaPickerController pops up and choose which song to play. It plays fine in the app but when I exit the app and go into it again the music stops. Any idea?

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate> 
{    
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
    IBOutlet UIButton *music;
    IBOutlet UIButton *stopmusic;   
}

- (IBAction)music:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)stopmusic:(id)sender
{    
    [musicPlayer stop];
}

- (IBAction)music:(id)sender
{
    MPMediaPickerController *musicSelect;
    musicSelect = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
    musicSelect.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:musicSelect animated:YES completion: nil];
}

- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker
  didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [musicPlayer play];
}

- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: I was experiencing the same issues when I was trying to build a simple music player but didn't invest the time to figure out why this was happening. I would suggest looking into `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` which should help you debug when playback state is being changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad method register a notification for when app enters foreground:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(notification:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Then have a method that gets executed whenever app enter foreground again. Use the instance property to replay the music again.

```
- (void)notification:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Notification: %@", sender);
    // add code to play again        

}
```